# JQuery Autopopulate

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery so any help will be very much appreciated

I have a group of radio buttons having same name ..

```
<input id="employeeType" type="radio" name="employee_type" value="Ongoing" <?php echo set_radio('employee_type', 'Ongoing', TRUE); ?>/> Ongoing &nbsp;

<input id="employeeType" type="radio" name="employee_type" value="Casual" <?php echo set_radio('employee_type', 'Casual'; ?>/> Casual &nbsp;
```

Based on the selection above the text feild must be auto populated .. If the user selects Casual, the text field will have to auto populate with text "N/A" otherwise the user will have to type their text in...

```
<input name="work_type" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('work_type'); ?>" size="20" maxlength="20">
```

Can someone please help me acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should give your radio boxes different ID's. ID's should always be unique.

The easiest way to achieve what you want would be to attach a click handler to your radio inputs, check the value and act accordingly:

```
$("[name='employee_type']").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val == "Casual") {
        $("[name='work_type']").val("N/A");
    } else {
        $("[name='work_type']").val("");
    }
});
```

If user clicks "Casual", work type will contain "N/A", otherwise it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[name="employee_Type"]').click(function() { 
  var $input = $(':input[name="work_type"]');
  console.log(this.value);

  if (this.value === "Casual") { 
    $input.val("N/A");
  } else { 
    $input.val(''); 
  }

});
```

Link to a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/36YU3/)...